# Oracle substring

Tags: sql, oracle

I have been trying to get just first string before the semicolon in the given string

```
H-Henry Grey;CA;UID123;09870;
```

In the above case I would like to get anything before first semicolon and after 'H-', which would give me just Henry Grey. The below query gives me everything after H-. Any help is appreciated . Thanks.

```
select SUBSTR(log,INSTR(log,'H-')) from table1; -- log is the column name of table table1
```

Comment: Is the initial part, which you must remove, always `'H-'`? If not, what else can it be (and why do you expect us to be able to guess that without you saying it explicitly)? Also - what do you want returned - if anything - if either the "initial part" or the semicolon are missing? What if the input string is `'Alexandre Dumas - MN - blah blah blah'`? If both the initial fragment and the semicolon are **always** present, please say so - to avoid questions like mine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with the regex pattern `H-([_;]+)`, then replace with the first capture group:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR('H-Henry Grey;CA;UID123;09870;', 'H-([^;]+)', 1, 1, NULL, 1)
FROM dual;  -- outputs Henry Grey
```

### Demo

Comment: Thank you !! It worked . I will look for the explanation of the arguments , Thank you again .

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have already found a good way to solve your problem, but for future reference you may want to review [Oracle's Documentation for `SUBSTR`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/sqlrf/SUBSTR.html#GUID-C8A20B57-C647-4649-A379-8651AA97187E).

Notice that there are three parameters: the first is the string that you want to get a substring of, the second is *position* which indicates the character where the substring begins, and the third is *substring_length* which indicates the length of the substring.

In your example, if you just wanted all characters before the first `;`, without worrying about the `H-` you could do: `SUBSTR(log, 1, INSTR(log, ';')-1)`. Notice that the *position* is 1-based, so SUBSTR(log, 1, ...) gives you a substring beginning with the first character of the input string.

And if you just wanted the characters after `H-` without worrying about the `;` you could do: `SUBSTR(log, INSTR(log, 'H-')+2)`. Notice that the default for *substring_length* is the rest of the input string.

When you combine these two to get the substring between `H-` and `;` you get:

```
SQL> insert into table1 values('H-Henry Grey;CA;UID123;09870;');

1 row created.

SQL> 
SQL> select substr(log, instr(log, 'H-')+2, instr(log, ';') - (instr(log, 'H-')+2))
  2    from table1;

SUBSTR(LOG,INSTR(LOG,'H-')+2,INSTR(LOG,';')-(INSTR(LOG,'H-')+2))                
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Henry Grey
```